# Chisel3 based Hardware Accelerator for Risc-V Rocket generator?

Tags: riscv, chisel

Is it possible to use chisel3 for building hardware accelerator and connect to rocket generator? I have noticed that rocket generator is written in old chisel Version. Can we connect this kind of hardware accelerator to core through ROCC interface and test them.

I know this is a theoretical question but brief explanation would be beneficial to everyone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is yes. Rocket-chip builds under chisel3, in order to do this it uses a backward compatibility mode. An example repo that is an example is here: [rocket-dsp-utils](https://github.com/ucb-art/rocket-dsp-utils), it's a good, but complex starting point for seeing how dsp blocks and other designs can be added to rocket. Perhaps some different users have other examples, that are little less complicated.